# angular js how to gat data from using $http

Tags: angularjs

in angular js how to gat data from data base using $HTTP
how to solution my problem give me dital and program dital spat by spat  examination and program

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get data from database using `$http`. You have to make web services in php, django,node etc then you have to call web service using `$http.post` or `$http.get` based on method which is created by you.

Web service frameworks are...

http://www.slimframework.com/

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 0):

using $http service, you can only make http request to http server.In this service you can only mention the path/url of file or api(in case of REST API) from where you have to make ajax call.You can't use sql query from remote database.If you want to get data from database using $http then you can call an API which resides in server.That API will take your request and pass it to Stored procedures(PL/SQL) and stored procedures interact with database with SQL queries to get desired data and provide to API and then API make response with data to you which you can get in success callback.